# Merge only changed files to unrelated branch

Tags: git

In our repository we have two long living branches: `main` (green) & `staging` (blue).
These do not have a common parent, they are completely unrelated.

What I'm trying to do is branch off of `main`, do some commits and then merge to `staging`.
[image]

What I've done so far is to cherry pick the orange commit into `staging`. But I'm wondering if I couldn't do it some other way.

I've tried the following:

```
git checkout staging
git merge feature --allow-unrelated-histories
```

But this caused chaos, 3000 mismatching files had conflicts, when the orange commit only contained a new file.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you aware that you can [cherry-pick a range of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-them-into-another-branch)?

Comment: Having the unrelated histories in the first place is probably the real error; but given that you *do* have unrelated histories, you won't be able to use `git merge` (at least, not usefully here). There are some sneaky tricks one can sometimes pull with `git replace` but it's probably better to just cherry-pick.

Comment: @torek you know what? I dug through the repo log and 5 years ago they did have a common parent. Will try and get the full repo and see if that helps.